# Wordpress PHP code not displaying in webpage

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, wordpress

I have been overcoming some issues on my own and teaching my self about Ubuntu. I have now got to point of installing word press. However it won't display anything I put in . I did try one of the plug in for wordpress php every were but still no luck. I am running

- Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu), Server built:   2017-06-26T11:58:04

```
PHP 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

mysql> SELECT @@version;
+-------------------------+
| @@version               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
```

- wordpress version 4.8

Everything when I check it tells me it is running correctly, have run the command to make sure php is enable to run.

I have done clean install thinking that I may have missed a command line entry some where but I fixed the mistakes I had which where to do with my spelling. I have read a number of forms tried as many ways as possible. Wordpress works ok. Just when I enter php code, it does not show it, the code works correctly in windows version of wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you kindly check required module are enable or not in your Ubuntu os. After that give permission to directory.
Also enable apache rewrite mode

Comment: hi Rashid I not sure where to check all but I do rember during the setup after install I had to put in command to enable php  and give apachie something the same

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)